# Selecting a word using starting and ending regex

Tags: regex, gherkin

I have this .feature file, syntax colored using the following patterns:

```
[
    {
        "match": '#(.*)$'
        "name": 'comment.line.gherkin'
    }
    {
        "match": '^\.\.\.(.*)$'
        "name": 'comment.line.gherkin'
    }
    {
        "match": '(^\*\*\*.*?\*\*\*)|((?<=^\|)\s+\*\*\*.*?\*\*\*)'
        "name": 'support.class.gherkin'
    }
    {
        "match": '(\$\{.*?\})|(@\{.*?\})'
        "name": 'string.single.qoute.gherkin'
    }
    {
        "match": '\s*(Scenario\:|Feature\:|Scenario Outline\:|Background\:|Examples\:)'
        "name": 'keyword.gherkin'
    }
    {
        "match": '\s*(Given|Then|When|And|But)'
        "name": 'support.class.gherkin'
    }
    {
        "match": '(?<=\s|^)(@[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)'
        "name": 'entity.name.function.decorator.gherkin'
    }
    {
        "begin": '(^[^ \t\*\n\|]+)|((?<=^\|)\s+[^ \t\*\n\|]+)'
        "end": '\s{2}|\t|$|\s+(?=\|)'
        "name": 'keyword.gherkin'
    }
    {
        "match": '\s(\d*)\s'
        "name": 'entity.name.function.decorator.gherkin'
    }
    {
        "match": '(\<\w+\>)'
        "name": 'constant.character.escape.feature'
    }
    {
        "match": "(\s\'.*?[^\']\'\s)"
        "name": 'string.single.qoute.gherkin'
    }
    {
        "match": '(\s\".*?[^\"]\"\s)'
        "name": 'string.double.qoute.gherkin'
    }
    {
        "match": "\[(\'.*?[^\']\')\]"
        "name": 'constant.character.escape.feature'
    }
    {
        "match": '(\[[^]]*\])'
        "name": 'constant.numeric.gherkin'
    }
    {
        "match": '\|\s(.*)\s\|'
        "name": 'constant.numeric.gherkin'
    }
]
```

The issue is that when I am trying to write small files using this grammar highlighting (without perfectly following gherkin structure), the regex pattern is highlighting everything under `'keyword.gherkin'` until it finds a keyword. 
This is the pattern bugging me:

```
      {
          "begin": '(^[^ \t\*\n\|]+)|((?<=^\|)\s+[^ \t\*\n\|]+)'
          "end": '\s{2}|\t|$|\s+(?=\|)'
          "name": 'keyword.gherkin'
      }
```

If I delete those lines, it works for what I need but I then I loose some text highlighting inside the file like `|1|2|3|` which isn't really a solution.

Let's put an example.

*Remember those regex are being evaluated constantly .*

I start typing at the document the word `Feature:` and while I type, it gets highlighted in red. Once I'm done and I keep writing, for exmample `Feature: do something` , *"Feature:"* is red and the rest of the text becomes standard color.
That will be correct behaviour.

For instance, if at the start of the document I start typing `will do something` it is highlighted in red, and it shouldn't be since there is not any gherking keyword in there.

What the *"name":* does in the patterns is stablish a syntax color, so it is not  relevant.

I have tried several modifications to the pattern without any success.

Here is a file example: https://regex101.com/r/qU5mY5/3

Am I targeting the wrong pattern? If not, anyone can throw me some light?

Comment: A suggestion - the knowledge at SO regarding `regex` vs. `gherkin` is roughly 600:1 (my own guesstimate based on number of followers ;). I for one don't even know *of* gherkin. Maybe you could give some more `regex` oriented examples of your input and what you expect.

Comment: @ClasG I'll add more examples, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST ISSUE**

Unwanted text is red highlighted when it should not (`will do something`).

The problem is located, as you correctly stated, in the first section of the second *keyword-regex*, specifically:

```
"begin": '(^[^ \\t\\*\\n\\|]+)|...'
```

It matches **everything** starting from the **beginning of the line** that is **not**:

- a space `' '`
- a tab `\t`
- a literal star `*`
- a newline `\n`
- a pipe `|`

So if a line **starts** with `will do something` it is matched till the regex engine does not encounter the **end-regex**: two spaces `\s{2}` or a tab `\t` or the end of line `$` or *"one or more spaces"* followed by a pipe `\s+(?=\|)`.

**SECOND ISSUE**:

If you want to match a line starting exactly with `|1|2|3|` you have to modify the second section of the *begin-regex*, with optional spaces `\s*` like this:

```
 "begin": '...|((?<=^\\|)\\s*[^ \\t\\*\\n\\|]+)'
```

**Online simulation** that illustrates these behaviours [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/qU5mY5/1).

---

This may gives you enough informations to solve your problems but if you need a specific solution i need more details on what exactly a **gherkin keyword** can be apart from one of:

```
'\\s*(Scenario\\:|Feature\\:|Scenario Outline\\:|Background\\:|Examples\\:)'
```

**PS**: probably in the above regex the colon doesn't need to be escaped and can be grouped. Also if two strings have substring in common, place the longest first to match correctly (or always order the elements from the longest to the shortest in a *OR-list* to allow the longest string is matched when it occurs):

```
"match": '\\s*(Scenario Outline|Background|Examples|Scenario|Feature):'
```

**UPDATE**

I've updated the regex online to match the **pipe tables**. For what i've read and your examples the next regex should works for you:

```
 {
     "begin": '(\|\s+[^ \t\*\n\|]+)'
     "end": '($|\s{2}|\t|\s+(?=\|))'
     "name": 'keyword.gherkin'
 }
```

Online updated version [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/qU5mY5/4)

**UPDATE 2**

Reading the gherking docs you have linked i've decide you want the *placeholder* you may found in *pipe-table* **header** highlighted as *keyword.gherkin* (red), instead the numeric value of the table have to be highlighted as *constant.numeric.gherkin*. If so you have to replace both with this:

```
 {
     "match": '\|(\s*[a-zA-Z][\w\']+\s*\|)+\s*$'
     "name": 'keyword.gherkin'
 }
 {
     "match": '\|(\s*[\d\.]+\s*\|)+\s*$'
     "name": 'constant.numeric.gherkin'
 }
```

The keyword.gherkin matches any pipe sequence `| h1 | h2 |...| hn |` with headers composed by *words* starting with a letter `[a-zA-Z]` (can be followed by letters, numbers, underscore `_` or single quote `'`).

The second (constant.numeric.gherkin) matches similarly a pipe sequence `| N1 | N2 | ... | Nn |` but the fields can be only numbers (also in decimal form is `123.25`).

**UPDATE 3**

Viewing your example file we can remove the *'keyword.gherkin'* regex at all and update the *'constant.numeric.gherkin'* regex as follows:

```
{
    "match": '\|(.+\|)+'
    "name": 'constant.numeric.gherkin'
}
```

**PS**: this regex highlights the *pipe-tables* irrespective of the chars inside. It's not anymore a "numeric" only regex, but i think it is what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understood the problem, but I am still unable to fix it, since when I try to modify the problematic regex, it breaks that '|1|2|' which should keep highlighted. 

The question is if there is any regex fix that still matches the keywords (those) , and doesn't break the rest. If the regex starts mathing the special keyword only, that would be fine too.

I give you a gherkin syntax link if you need it, but since everything else is correct, I don't think it'll be that helpful: http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/1.gherkin.html.

File: https://regex101.com/r/qU5mY5/2

Comment: @sailens: i've updated the answer modifying the regex to match the pipe tables, with an online implementation based on your example text. Tell me it works as expected for you (i've noticed you remove the double escape, better!)

Comment: Thats quite it! Now it interferes with the last regex in the list (see it here: https://regex101.com/r/sU8fD7/1). I'll give it a try to solve it from your approach, but I'll appreciate if you can find the correct answer before me ;)

Comment: @sailens: i've updated both the keyword and constant numeric regexp to match what i suppose do you need. The *keyword-regex* matches the headers of the pipe-tables, the *constant-numeric-regex* the rows filled with numeric values. If i misunderstood your request please clarify to me with an example of text with each line annotated with the correct highlight (with a simple parenthesis annotation right or above the text).

Comment: I modified your last regex option by `\|(\s*[\d\w\.]+\s*\|)+\s*$` because alphanumeric is allowed and that's almost it! Here's the current status: https://pad.riseup.net/p/regexHelp . Everything else is perfect. I am really grateful for the effort you are making on this :) Also for all the comment, I am learning a lot while reading you an trying to do it myself

Comment: @sailens: i've updated the regex again: remove the *keyword* regex and update the *numeric* regex to match any chars inside tables. **PS**: i'm glad you enjoy the *resolution* process, this site is meant to ease the process of mutual learnig. About your regex update note that ``\d = [0-9]`` is already included in ``\w = [0-9a-zA-Z_]``. Let me know if the last update works!

Comment: Now this is perfect! Thank you again for your availability :)